# Query to get one entry from multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

**Query:**

```
select machinename, StatusCode, max(size) as size, statusID
from machine where MachineID In( '33','22') and StatusCode = 166 
group by machinename, StatusCode, statusID
order by max(size) DESC
```

**Result:**

```
   machinename  StatusCode  size statusID
    -----------  ----------  ---- --------
    test1        166         50       1
    test1        166         25       2
    test2        166         75       3
    test2        166         48       4
```

**Requirement:**

I need to display only one entry for each machine.
I have to do this by taking the max size value between the two entries as shown above.
like for test1 i have two sizes 50 and 25 I have to show the row which has 50 and ignore row which has 25.

Thanks

**Desired Result:**

```
 machinename  StatusCode  size statusID
    -----------  ----------  ---- --------
    test1        166         50       1  
    test2        166         75       3
```

Comment: thanks john. was about to fix it.. that was quick.. :)

Comment: +1 At first look I thought this was going to be really simple, but I can't figure it out without using some form of Mark's solution!

Comment: It should also be noted that you *MIGHT* have some normalization issues with your database. You said that StatusID is the primary key, so the fact that you have repeating groups suggests there might be a problem. Is StatusCode functionally dependent on StatusID or machinename? And since machinename is presumably dependent on MachineID, that appears to be an anomaly on its own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT machinename, StatusCode, size, statusID
FROM (
    SELECT
        machinename,
        StatusCode,
        size,
        statusID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MachineID ORDER BY size DESC) AS rn
    FROM machine
    WHERE MachineID IN ('33','22')
    AND StatusCode = 166 
) T1
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY size DESC
```

Comment: This worked perfect, can you explain me the "ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MachineID ORDER BY size DESC) AS rn" if you dont mind. Like what is it actually doing